# How to create query from post value combined with repeater value

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have problems with creating a query based on the repeater field (ACF-plugin Wordpress). I use pages with a specific template. Every page title stands for a continent. Every repeater field stands for a country.

What I have so far:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'page',
    'post_parent' => 0,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'   => '_wp_page_template', 
            'value' => 'page-landing.php'
        )
    )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
        if( have_rows('countries') ):
            while ( have_rows('countries') ) : the_row(); ?>
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title=""><?php the_sub_field('country'); ?></a></li>
            <?php endwhile;
            else :
        endif; ?>

        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title=""><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

    <?php endwhile;
endif;
```

the results:

- Gambia (repeater value from Africa)
- Zimbabwe (repeater value from Africa)
- Africa (page)
- Belgium (repeater value from Europe)
- Germany (repeater value from Europe)
- Netherlands (repeater value from Europe)
- Europe (page)

How do I combine all those values alphabetically so I can create a permalink to the parent page, the continent?

Comment: what you want do you want to change plugin functionality?

Comment: It is already alphabetically ordered? do you not want the continent to be grouped with the countries? (ie : Europe, Belgium, Germany, Netherlands)

Comment: I'd like to group all results (continent and countries on same level), so I can order them all in alphabetical order. Now only the repeater fields are alphabetically ordered.